# I'm getting a "EOFError: EOF when reading a line" Error while executing a code on hackerrank

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler230/problem) problem -
but getting the above mentioned error at `n=int(input())` 
here's my code:

```
q=int(input())
z=""
for i in range(1,q+1):
    A = input()
    print()
    B = input()
    print()
    n=int(input())

    if len(A)>100 or len(B)>100:
      print("error")

    else:

       def fib(A, B):

           for i in range(1,100):
              C=A+B
              A=B
              B=C
              i=i+1
              global z
              z=B
              if len(B)>=n:
                  break


fib(A,B)
print(z[n-1])
```

while i'm not sure my answer is correct but at least i shouldn't be 
getting that error.

Comment: Did you choose Python 2 or Python 3 before submission?

Comment: yes I did choose python3

Comment: Just a guess: You should use one input in the loop (instead of three) and you should not print empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the EOF error because the three variables in each test case are in one space-separated line, not each on a line by itself. Here's an example of a way you could read them in:

```
A, B, n_str = input().split()
n = int(n_str)
```